# Using F# in C# as dll

Tags: c#, dll, f#

Is it possible to use an F# project as an assembly in a C# project?

If yes; as F# is faster than C# for calculation stuffs (isn't it?), if the calculation part of the code is in F# and the main project is in C#, does it make the application faster?

Comment: 1, Yes, it's possible. 2, It depends, especially on the developer's fluency in F# and C#. 3, It depends as well.

Comment: @Heinzi : I thought when it comes to C#, it may have not its real speed! Can you explain it for me a little more?

Comment: @mrbm: Why do you think that "it may not have its real speed"?

Comment: @Heinzi: I thought it may be some kind of re-compiling in C# !

Comment: You might find the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/142985/162396) helpful.

Comment: You may want to look at the FAQ when trying to decide what sorts of questions to post in the future @mrbm. Especially this part: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Asking if F# is faster than C# is a pretty open-ended question by definition because the answer (as was pointed out) is "it depends on the actual context".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use an F# project as an assembly in a C# project.

No, F# is not *per se* faster than C#. Both are compiled into the same type of Intermediate Language and run by the same .net Framework. You might be able to use some specific feature of F# to write a fast algorithm more elegantly than you would in C#, but that depends highly on the algorithm.

Comment: I didn't got it? Both are compiled into the same type! So you mean it's the algorithm that make F# faster! And this algorithm can't be written in C# like F#! Can you give me an example please?

Comment: F# and C# and all .net languages (i think) are compiled to the same intermediate language. Therefore any speed increase comes from the code you write in the language, not the fact that you're writing in C# or F#. Anything C# can do F# can do and visa-versa (i think, may be some edge cases). It might be *easier* to implement some given algorithm in one language or the other, so while both can be fast, it might be *easier* in one particular language.

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, F# is a .NET language and will provide a compliant dll
- F# is not faster. F# provides a better way of expressing certain types of problems. It therefore reduces amounts of bugs and increases productivity. F# also greatly encourages a programming model that is stateless, more scalable and gives a clear separation of data and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can and it makes sense. I personally use that approach in my projects.
But the fact that you express a calculation in F# instead of C# doesn't mean that your code will run faster or slower.
Of course, if you are familiar with functional programming you'll write faster your calculation code and in a more concise and elegant way, which will also allow you to test, maintain and reason about your code easily.